# ECS 945GCT-M/1333 change to only 1 core running

Tags: cpu

I am wondering how can l with the ECS 945GCT-M/1333 to change so it only runs one core and not both.

Comment: I doubt you can do that. So far I've never seen a motherboard which allows user to turn off a core in the processor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows; Windows can be configured to only run one core.  One Windows XP the [boot.ini](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833721) can be [manually edited](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289022).  Adding to the end of your boot line /numproc=1 will limit Windows to one core (since each core is considered a CPU)

Vista/7 is more complex.  For Vista or 7 I'd use [Easy BCD Edit](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).  Use the [Advanced Settings](http://neosmart.net/gallery/photo/view/neosmart/EasyBCD/EasyBCD+2.0/Advanced+Settings+Developer/) to limit Windows on one CPU.

Also if you only want to run limit a single program to a single CPU you can use [the procedure here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/start-an-application-assigned-to-a-specific-cpu-in-windows-vista/) to do that.

[image]